# how to access package explorer element in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins

i am making an eclipse plugin which make a ui on right clicking a project in eclipse workspce . the ui contains text fields , package explorer for the current project and directory explorer for current project.
i have successfully made a ui which appears on clicking a menu item on right clicking the project but it seems i can't make any jface or swt ui since they are not visible when we are using eclipse command hadlers .so in order to overcome it i made dialog pages but they have limited dialog like directorty dialog and file dialog and that too for entire window directory..... but i want package explorer and directory explorer for the project i just chose like it happens when u try making a new class in  a project the browse buttons just show packages and directory struture w.r.t to current selection

am i doin things wrong or is there a way out please suggest .....

Comment: I dont think its a good idea to put your email on a website, as a honeypot for spam.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit unclear to me, what the 'UI' is about. If you plan to embed the package and directory views inside a dialog next to each other, then I think you have to build similar lists on your own, since they are views with their own event logic. But if you plan to use them via the browse buttons as describes, take a look at [this](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/07/selection-dialogs-in-eclipse.html) page. It gives a good overview of the available selection dialogs in eclipse.

It is also always a good practice to search for code in eclipse that does nearly the same you want to do.

As an example, take a look at the new class wizard from the jdt.ui plug-in (This is the wizard you mentioned in your question): Press Cmd-Shift-T and begin typing 'newclass' and open NewClassWizardPage from org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards. This works as expected if you imported all jdt plug-ins as (binary) projects.

Take a look at the createControl method and dive into the createXXXControls methods via F3 and try to find out how JDT is doing the job.

As an alternative, open the desired selection dialog class (again with Cmd-Shift-T) and open the call hierarchy of that class...